# Stop pie chart at rotated angle core-plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-plot

i m rotating pie chart through following code

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];    
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI_4]; 
    rotation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI_4+10]; 
    rotation.duration  = 1.0f;
    rotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    rotation.delegate = self;
     pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4+10;
    [pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
    return YES;
}
```

But after rotation pie chart get back to it's initial position.But i want that now pie chart  should be at rotated angle. how to get success here?

Answer (score 0):

See [this CocoaDev article](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CoreAnimation). It gives a couple of possible solutions. Their example uses the `position` property, but the techniques discussed will work for any animatable properties.